# GNAT Programming Studio (IDE) and STM32 problems

Tags: ada, stm32f4discovery, gnat-gps

I’m using the Ada programming IDE GNAT Programming Studio (GPS, GPL 2017 release) and I’m having a hard time when I try to use it with STM32F4Disco.

On Linux (Ubuntu 17.10), when I try to open a STM32 project, GPS freezes. No core-dump, no error message. No exception message in .gsp/log but look like it didn't finish loading.

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Edit:
I installed GNAT 2017, Spark and arm-elf for Linux from AdaCore website.

Edit 2: I remove my question about GPS on Mac because it might be considered software-hardware questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is specifically for programming questions. For hardware-related problems, please ask your question on [**SuperUser**](http://www.superuser.com) instead. For further information, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)' for StackOverflow, and what questions [**shouldn't be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here. I'd also recommend taking the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hi @ObsidianAge, my question is about my problem with the programming tool GPS (Gnat programming studio). I thought Stackoverflow was appropriate. My apologies, if it is not the case.

Comment: @smionean This question is quite on topic!

Comment: Are you sure that you are using GPS installed with GNAT GPL, and not an older one, which Ubuntu has inherited from Debian?  The version of GPS currently in Debian is known to freeze/break occasionally.

Comment: @ObsidianAge GPS = GNAT Programming Studio = an IDE for Ada, C, C++ and Python development.  Please think before you down-vote.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen , I installed from AdaCore on a freshly built machine (virtual machine). Which Linux distro do you recommend? I don’t mind to switch.

Comment: IMHO it's on topic - it's a question about a development tool

Comment: I have to agree - this question is on topic. Quite sad how ppl are quick to downvote a question without understanding what is being asked.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this question (and at the time of me writing this comment **no-one** has down-voted it), though the **initial** wording in this question (it has been changed substantially) made me think it was about GPS hardware, and a hardware-related question would be better suited to SuperUser. With the revisions to this question it is now clear that it is about GNAT Programming Studio, and as such, this is indeed a good question for StackOverflow. My apologies for the initial vote to close -- I've now voted to re-open this :)

Comment: @smionean Please post your solution as an answer.  Both to keep the record straight, and make it easy to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install 32 bits support. On Ubuntu/Debian execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```